# Force Angular to wait for my function's response

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I am creating a custom pipe and calling the google translation service API inside it.
The returned value is the value before translation because the function finished execution after the value was returned. I tried async/await/Promise with no luck.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleTranslationService } from 'src/app/google.translation.service';
@Pipe({
  name: 'usdInr'
})
export class UsdInrPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private googleTranslationService: GoogleTranslationService){
  }
   transform(value: String, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
    translatedValue:String;
    let model={
      "q": [value],
      "target": "ar"
    };
    console.log("// BEFORE TRANSLATION //"+ value);  //printed first
     this.googleTranslationService.translate(model).subscribe((response:any)=>{
      value=response.data.translations[0].translatedText
      console.log("// AFTER TRANSLATION //"+ value); //printed third
    })
    console.log("// AFTER FUNCTION //"+ value); //printed second
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: return the observable from your pipe and then call the `| async` pipe to "unwrap" the observable. or look through asyn pipe sources and try to implement something simillar

Answer (score 0):

In your custom pipe, you should return an observable.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs';

transform(value: String, ...args: unknown[]): Observable<String> {
  let translatedValue: String;
  let model = {
    q: [value],
    target: 'ar',
  };

  return this.googleTranslationService
    .translate(model)
    .pipe(
      map((response: any) => response.data.translations[0].translatedText)
    );
}
```

Or you may return the `Promise` as below:

```
import { firstValueFrom, map, Observable, switchMap } from 'rxjs';

async transform(value: String, ...args: unknown[]) {

  let model = {
    q: [value],
    target: 'ar',
  };

  return await firstValueFrom(
    this.googleTranslationService
      .translate(model)
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => response.data.translations[0].translatedText)
      )
  );
}
```

And in your view, you should apply the `AsyncPipe` after your custom pipe.

```
{{ input | usdInr | async }}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sgzncz?file=src%2Fusd-inr.pipe.ts)